# python pandas, replace function apply to multiple dataframes at once

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dict such as:

```
elements_to_replace= {r'.\(MoM\)': ' MoM', 
                      r'.% m/m': ' MoM', 
                      r'.\(QoQ\)': ' QoQ', 
                      r'.\(WoW\)': ' WoW'}
```

and 3 dataframes `df1`, `df2` and `df3`. Currently I use the replace function on all 3 dataframes and it works.

```
df1.replace(elements_to_replace, regex=True)
df2.replace(elements_to_replace, regex=True)
df3.replace(elements_to_replace, regex=True)
```

Is there a way to apply the replace function on those 3 dataframes at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that [`pd.DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), by default, does not modify the DataFrame, it just returns a modified *copy*.

using the `inplace` parameter, though, you could do the following:

```
for df in [df1, df2, df3]:
    df.replace(elements_to_replace, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Following this, `df1`, `df2`, and `df3`, should have the modifications.